# How do i save my results to a txt file and not use print line?

Tags: java, sorting

Completely new to java and having a nightmare! I have a list of 235886 words shuffled.txt, that I've managed to sort into ascending order, however it takes a lifetime to run, so I was thinking would it be possible to save my results to a txt file.  How would I go about this?

All help gratefully received. 
Cheers

```
public class Main {
static final int NUMWORDS = 235886;
static final String FILENAME = "shuffled.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = readWords(FILENAME, NUMWORDS);
    String[] myStringArray = readWords(FILENAME, NUMWORDS);
    sortedWords(words);
}

// 5. Write code to build a sorted version of the list (in ascending order) 
public static void sortedWords(String unsorted[]) {
    sort(unsorted);

    for (int n=0 ;  n <  unsorted.length; n++ ) {
        System.out.println(unsorted[n]);
        // return unsorted;
    }

}static void sort(String[] unsorted){

    for (int i =0; i< unsorted.length; i += 1) {
        int j = findMinIndex(unsorted, i + 1, i);
        if (j != -1) {
            swap(unsorted, i, j);
        }
    }
}

static int findMinIndex(String[] numbers, int startIndex, int minIndex) {
    if (numbers.length <= startIndex) {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i=startIndex; i < numbers.length; i += 1){
        if (numbers[i].length() > numbers[minIndex].length()){
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
static void swap(String[] numbers, int i, int j) {
    String tmp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = tmp;
}


private static String[] readWords (String filename,int count){
    String[] words = new String[count];

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        int i = 0;
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null && i < count; ) {
            words[i++] = line;
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File: " + filename + " could not be found.");
    }
    return words;
}
}
```

Comment: To write the result into a file, you would go a similar way as reading them. Instead of a `BufferedReader` you ... well. need a `BufferedWriter`. You can google easily for examples on how to write a String / multiple Strings to a file.

Comment: If you know how to read from a file you should be able to write one too. There are lots of tutorials on that. However, I doubt your main problem is output but rather the O(n^2) complexity of your code: you're iterating over the array and in `findMinIndex()` you're iterating again which basically results in n * n/2 iterations (and thus basically O(n^2 ). A good sort algorithm should have O(log(n)) complexity, which for 235k words should result in about 3 million iterations instead of about 27 billion with your approach. Why don't you use `Arrays.sort(...)`?

Comment: There's no point in reading in the file a second time into `myStringArray` as it's unused.

Comment: O(n log n) @Thomas

Comment: Primarily the time is lost in sorting. You could test it with `Arrays.sort` instead.

Comment: @yacc right, I knew I missed something :)

Answer (score 0):

"Save my results to a txt file." This is how you put every single from your `String[] words` array.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

String[] words; //Imagine this has a lot of data inside
try {
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 
   for(String str: words) {
     writer.write(str);
     writer.write("\n");
   }
   writer.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e);
}
```

Comment: Cheers Joe, Im so sorry but this is doing my head in, could I ask where abouts id put this code into what I already have? Thanks very much

Comment: Just put the try and catch part after when you sort your array called words, so after `sortedWords(words);` In case you don't understand the "for" part, it is just saying to the computer: for each String (that I named "str") that you find inside the array "words", I want you to write every line that you find in words, then a carriage return. Consider in marking this the answer to help other people :)

Comment: Replace your for loop with a print statement by the try-catch loop here.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your method `sortedWords` into this one (needs Java 8 or 9):

```
public static void sortedWords(String unsorted[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    sort(unsorted);

    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("sorted_words.txt")) {
        Arrays.stream(unsorted).forEach(out::println);
    }

}
```

That should do the trick and be relatively simple. Below is an alternative that will support UTF-8 for supporting a wider range of characters:

```
public static void sortedWords(String unsorted[]) throws IOException {
    sort(unsorted);

    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("sorted_words.txt"), "UTF-8"), true)) {
        Arrays.stream(unsorted).forEach(out::println);
    }

}
```

You might have to change the signature of the `main` method to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

so that the code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for-loop with `println` inside `sortedWords()`. After the call to `sortedWords` in `main` add this to output to the `sorted_words.txt` file:

```
java.nio.file.Files.write(Paths.path("sorted_words.txt"), Arrays.asList(words));
```